# ORA-01839 "date not valid for month specified" for to_date in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format, to-date

I have following query (`BOCRTNTIME - varchar e.g 2015-02-28 12:21:45, VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T - some view`):

```
select BOCRTNTIME
    from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
    where to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')
        between (to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
            and (to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

On executing I get error:

```
ORA-01839:  "date not valid for month specified"
```

I thought that there are can be incorrect data in `BOCRTNTIME`, so execute following query:

```
select distinct
         substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,8),
         substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2)
  from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
 order by substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2);
```

But everything looks fine: http://pastebin.com/fNjP4UAu.
Also following query executes without any error:

```
select to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T;
```

I already tried add `trunc()` to all `to_date()` but no luck. Also I create pl/sql procedure that takes one by one item form `VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T` and convert it to date - and everything works just fine.
Any ideas why I get error on first query?

UPD: Query on table that used in view works fine, but in view - not

UPD2: We have few enviroments with same products, but get error only on one

UPD3: Issue was resolved by search non valid dates in table that used in view

Comment: the select of this `select substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10)`  is `"2015-07-"` ? if yes then thats the problem if your error . it should containt a day value to work fine ,  for example "2015-07-01". what is the value of BOCRTNTIME?

Comment: Can you post the results of your link? its blocked for me.

Comment: When you tried `select to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T;` did you make sure you selected all rows? Some tools like SQL-Developer will only show e.g. 50 results; the error could appear with a later result.

Comment: What is the DDL statement that produces the view?

Comment: @MT0  there are view: pastebin.com/UntX5FfV and table used in view: pastebin.com/PcFppgAg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what might be happening is that Oracle is pushing the predicate to the underlying tables of the view.

Have you tried to run the query

```
select to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') BOCRTNTIME
from MY_TABLE
```

instead of querying the view?

you can also confirm this by using the NO_PUSH_PRED hint

```
select /*+ NO_PUSH_PRED(VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T) */
BOCRTNTIME
from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
where 
to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between (to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and (to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: @Moudiz: what do you mean?

Comment: Quering on table, not view, works fine, but on view with NO_PUSH_PRED hint still fails

Comment: @DmitryKompot can you maybe provide the scripts for building the table and the view and also insert scripts?

Comment: I don't have insert scripts, but there are view: http://pastebin.com/UntX5FfV and table used in view: http://pastebin.com/PcFppgAg

Comment: What happens when you do the following:

`create table my_tab_test as select * from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T`

and afterwards run the same  query on the newly created table?

`select 
BOCRTNTIME
from MY_TAB_TEST
where 
to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between (to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and (to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: @DmitryKompot have you tried with creating a table from the view?

Comment: Select from MY_TAB_TEST works fine.
Also there is execution plan from sql developer that i get from select from view with NO_PUSH_PRED hint http://pastebin.com/G2mkvzEH

Comment: @DmitryKompot Then the problem is with predicate pushing as I suspected. 
Your execution plan shows that the predicate is pushed to the table 
 `   TABLE ACCESS  BODAT_QUALITYCLAIM    12631    188975 
  Filter Predicates 
  AND 
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(BODAT_QUALITYCLAIM.BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')>=TO_DATE(' 2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: @DmitryKompot can you maybe review how you use the NO_PUSH_PRED? and can you also run the TO_DATE query against  BODAT_QUALITYCLAIM

Comment: I just exec query provided by you `select /*+ NO_PUSH_PRED (VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T) */
BOCRTNTIME
from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
where 
to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between (to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and (to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`.
TO_DATE query against BODAT_QUALITYCLAIM  work just fine

Comment: And what wrong with predicate pushed to the table? From my point of view everything fine. Also is there any way to not use hints?

Comment: Hi @DmitryKompot,
The problem is that there is lots of data in the table that might not end up in the view. The where conditions in the view are filtering the data and therefore you don't get the problem while querying the view just with TO_DATE as part of the SELECT. With predicate_pushing, oracle is forcing this condition to be evaluated agains a bigger set of data (perhaps all data in your table) , where you probably have invalid dates, casing the whole query to fail.

Comment: The idea of predicate pushing is to improve performance by evaluating filtering crytheria in the deepest level of the view therefore reducing the amount of data to process and also taking advantage of indexes wherever possible

Comment: Hi @DmitryKompot Can you maybe try again using an alias for the view?
`select /*+ NO_PUSH_PRED(V) */ V.BOCRTNTIME from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T V where to_date(substr(V.BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between (to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and (to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: @DmitryKompot Please try again with the query above, I think that the problem was not the alias but the blank space between NO_PUSH_PRED and the Brackets

Comment: Thanks, I find incorrect dates in BODAT_QUALITYCLAIM.

Answer (score 4):

A bit too long for a comment - create a simple function to test the dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_Valid_Date(
  in_string VARCHAR2,
  in_format VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  dt DATE;
BEGIN
  dt := TO_DATE( in_string, in_format );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT BOCRTNTIME
FROM   VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
WHERE  is_Valid_Date( substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10) ) = 0;
```

You will possibly find that April, June, September or November have an entry for the 31st of that month or February has values greater than 28/29th (although I can't see anything like that in your pasted data).

Otherwise you could try using ANSI Date literals:

```
SELECT BOCRTNTIME
FROM   VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
WHERE  to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between DATE '2016-01-01' and DATE '2016-02-01';
```

or, even simpler, given the format of the input:

```
SELECT BOCRTNTIME
FROM   VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
WHERE  substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10) between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-01';
```

Comment: First query (with function) return nothing,
Second - ORA-01839,
And what about third - I don't think that compare dates as varchar - good idea

Comment: You have the dates stored in ISO8601 format (or near enough) - there is no issue with using a string comparison to test if a **valid** date is within a date range using this format. That was one of the reasons for which the format was designed.

Comment: Thanks, using your function and idea from @Ricardo Arnold about running it against table, but not view I find errorneus date records

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long shot but [between](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm) doesn't have parenthesis in it's syntax, have you tried removing them?

```
select
    BOCRTNTIME
    from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T
    where 
    to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') between to_date ('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date ('2016-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: I'll find it very surprising if this is the cause to the error.

Comment: No, even `where to_date(substr(BOCRTNTIME,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_date ('2015-06-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` not work

Comment: Well, it was worth trying in the case oracle was only considering the entire parenthesis as an argument for the lower limit in the between clause..

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you have an invalid day in your month. Check your data with this:

```
-- Check for months with 30 days
select substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2), substr(BOCRTNTIME,6,2) from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T where to_number(substr(BOCRTNTIME,6,2)) in (4,6,9,11) and to_number(substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2))>30;

-- Check for february
select substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2), substr(BOCRTNTIME,6,2) from VIEW_BASE_MARIX_T where to_number(substr(BOCRTNTIME,6,2))=2 and to_number(substr(BOCRTNTIME,9,2))>28;
```

Comment: As you can see from my pastebin link there is no such items