# Extract date from string oracle

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have a column in which a string starts with - 'Chicago, IL, April 20, 2015 — and so on text here'. I want to extract the Date part from this string in Oracle. Any ideas on how to do this. I was able to find something for mm/dd/yyyy like below, but not for long date format.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(' the meeting will be on 8/8/2008', '[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{2,}') FROM dual
```

Comment: Will the date always have the same format, e.g. `full_month_name day, year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns value is always start with `'Chicago, IL, April 20, 2015 — and so on text here'` then you could simly use `SUBSTR` instead of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(column_name
        ,INSTR(column_name, ',', 1, 2) + 1
        ,INSTR(column_name, '—') - INSTR(column_name, ',', 1, 2) - 1
    ) 
FROM 
    dual;
```

If not then you could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as other answer mention, my original answer is wrong as `@MTO` comment

Comment: The regular expression will match: `Regarding point 42, 1984 is a fantastic book`. or even `99, 0000`.

Comment: MTO got it, thank you. @user747291 you should update your query according to other answer. Mine is editted.

Comment: Your `SUBSTR/INSTR` query will only work for 5-character month names and 2-digit days. If you want to match `May 1, 1900` or `December 25, 2016` then they are not 14 characters. It also relies on the date being appended with a hyphen (not sure this is always the case).

Comment: @MT0 I used **INSTR - 14** to get `length_of_substr`, not get only 14 characters. **14** is started index of `SUBSTR(column_name, started_index, length_of_substr)`

Comment: Ok, but then it won't work if the month is at the start of the string or if the OP picks a longer or shorter city name or if there is no hyphen. 14 is a magic number that might work in this specific case but not generally.

Comment: MTO yes, so @user747291 you should check again to get your right answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT  TO_DATE(
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            'Chicago, IL, April 20, 2015 — and so on text here',
            '(JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|'
              || 'OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER)'
              || '[[:space:]]+([012]?[0-9]|3[01])'
              || '[[:punct:][:space:]]+\d{4}',
            1,
            1,
            'i'
          ),
          'MONTH DD YYYY'
        )
FROM    DUAL;
```

If you want to validate the dates as well (so you don't get an error for `February 29, 2001`) then you could use a user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parse_Date(
  in_string     VARCHAR2,
  in_format     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  in_nls_params VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_DATE( in_string, in_format, in_nls_params );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

And replace the `TO_DATE( ... )` function with `PARSE_DATE( ... )`

Comment: More general answer, should be the accepted one. I'd suggest changing `[12]?` to `[012]?` to catch dates like "April 01" though. Also it's still prone to errors like `February 31`, but catching all that with regexp is way too much work.

Comment: @Timekiller Updated to `[012]` and also added a way to handle erroneous dates (adapted from [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270553/1509264)).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can take a direct approach and use a regular expression like in the example that you've found:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('Chicago, IL, April 20, 2015 - etc etc', '(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}')
FROM dual;
```

But this will only work properly if all the dates are in the exact same format. Full month name with first letter uppercased, space, day, comma, space, 4-digit year. If there can be more than one space or no space at all, use `\s*` instead of spaces in the regular expression. If the month name isn't necessarily initcap, use `initcap()` on source or case-insensitive flag for `regexp_substr` function.

Additionally, this will catch bogus dates that fit the format, like "April 99, 1234", you'll have to filter them later.