# How to compare date to format date on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we compare a date to a format in Oracle?
Something like this:  if MyDate is on format DD MONTH YYYY THEN /....

elsif MyDate is on format YYYY-MONTH-DD Then...

EDIT: My dates are in varchar2 and i want to keep them that way. I want just to know how to write a regex that would reprensent for example 10 October 2010.

Is it possible ? If it is a regex how would its format be please

Comment: Could you please share your query ?

Comment: What do you mean? A DATE value in Oracle does not have any format. The (default) is just the **output** format. What is the data type of column `MyDate`?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: MyDate that should be stored as date!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What version of the database are you using?

Comment: Very bad idea when you say "dates are in varchar2 and I want to keep them that way"

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43633732/1509264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing what was mentioned in the comments to your question, best practice would be to have an actual `DATE` type field instead of `VARCHAR2`, and if you needed specific display formats, store those in another field as a format pattern. That said, you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` to check the format using the patterns in the below example.

```
with dateinfo as (
    select 1 as id, '2018-MARCH-10' as dtString from dual
    union all
    select 2 as id, '10 MARCH 2018' as dtString from dual ) 
select id, dtString, 
    case 
        when regexp_like(dtString, '^[0-9]{4}-.[a-zA-Z]{3,}-.[0-9]{1,2}$') then 'format1'
        when regexp_like(dtString, '^[0-9]{1,2} [a-zA-Z]{3,} [0-9]{4}$') then 'format2'
        else 'no format'
    end as dtFormat 
from dateinfo;
```